# separating bayer image to color channel c++

Tags: c++, performance, optimization

I have a raw image with different Bayer pattern.
this is what i have implemented in order to separate the channels.
speed is very important here since this is going to run on thousands of large images.

can you please suggest code optimizations.
I know % (modulo) isn't very fast how can i replace this for example?

thanks

```
void Utilities::SeparateChannels(int** _image, int*& gr, int*& r, int*& b, int*& gb,int _width, int _height, int _colorOrder)
{
    //swith case the color Order
    int counter_R = 0;
    int counter_GR = 0;
    int counter_GB = 0;
    int counter_B = 0;

    switch (_colorOrder)
    {
        //rggb
    case 0:

        for (int i = 0; i < _height; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < _width; j++)
            {
                if (i % 2 == 0 && j % 2 == 0)
                {
                    r[counter_R] = _image[i][j];
                    counter_R++;
                }
                else if (i % 2 == 0 && j % 2 == 1)
                {
                    gr[counter_GR] = _image[i][j];
                    counter_GR++;
                }
                else if (i % 2 == 1 && j % 2 == 0)
                {
                    gb[counter_GB] = _image[i][j];
                    counter_GB++;
                }
                else if (i % 2 == 1 && j % 2 == 1)
                {
                    b[counter_B] = _image[i][j];
                    counter_B++;
                }
            }
        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Actually, modulo is usually *very* fast when the second operand is a constant power of 2, as it always seems to be in the code above. If you want to, you could try `& 1` instead of `% 2`, but it probably won't make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility that *might* be worth considering would be to set up the arrays for the destination channel data as an array itself:

```
int *channels[] = {r, gr, gb, b};
```

Likewise, set up the counters as an array:

```
int counters[4] = {0};
```

...then your code could come out something like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<_height; i++)
    for (int j=0; j<_width; j++) {
        channel = (i&1) << 1 + (j&1);
        int &counter = counters[channel];

        channels[channel][counter++] = image[i][j];
    }
```

The basic idea is that we combine the low bits of the `i` and `j` into a single number that we can use as a channel address. Then we use that number to index into the channel and the counter for that channel.

It's possible your compiler is already optimizing the existing code to be roughly equivalent to this (or possibly even better than this produces), but it's also possible it isn't.

I wouldn't normally expect a lot of improvement (at least on a typical desktop computer) though. I'd expect the bottleneck to be the bandwidth to main memory, almost regardless of the details of how you write the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You should unroll the loop to process in 2x2 blocks. This way you will always know the parities and won't need to test them.

```
                r[counter_R] = _image[i][j];
                counter_R++;

                gr[counter_GR] = _image[i][j+1];
                counter_GR++;

                gb[counter_GB] = _image[i+1][j];
                counter_GB++;

                b[counter_B] = _image[i+1][j+1];
                counter_B++;
```

(Also adapt the loop parameters.)

Comment: If I am right you plan to do a nearest neighbor reconstruction. This will give you rather ugly results. (Bi)linear interpolation will be visually much better. If you want sheer speed, then SSE vectorization should be considered (but for this particular transform, it will be arduous; don't expect the compiler to help you).